# How to get the indexes of xgb.DMatrix to add information for feval function?

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost

I need to optimize xgboost parameters on a customized evaluation function.
But to do so, I need to join some other information about the selected observations to measure performance.

The best way for me would be to add the information directly to the xgb.DMatrix something like :

```
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = matrix, label = OBSERVATIONS$actual, ID = OBSERVATIONS$ID)
```

This way I would be able to retrieve what observations is being evaluated and join some additionnal information to evaluate. 
Something like :

```
feval = function(preds, dtrain){
# getting labels
actual <- getinfo(dtrain, "label")
# Retrieving additionnal information
ID <- getinfo(dtrain, "ID")
dt <- data.table(ID = ID, actual = actual, preds = preds)
# Note that it would work also work if there is a way to know what 
# is the index of the observations in dtrain

# Joining additional information
dt = scalingFact[dt, on = c("ID")]
```

Anyone knows if there is a way I can add the information either by index or with additionnal information I could had to the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a easy way of defining a

Maybe try setting attributes of dtrain, setting ID to be one of the attributes. I don't think it classes with other uses:

```
library(xgboost)
library(data.table)

# use iris
# fictitious id
iris$ID = 1:nrow(iris)
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data=as.matrix(iris[,-5]), 
label = as.numeric(iris[,5])-1)
# set attributes
attr(dtrain,'ID') <- iris$ID

mdl <- xgboost(dtrain,nrounds=3,objective="multi:softmax",num_class=3)
preds = predict(mdl,newdata=dtrain)

feval = function(preds, dtrain){
# getting labels
actual <- getinfo(dtrain, "label")
# Retrieving additionnal information
ID <- attr(dtrain,"ID")
dt <- data.table(ID = ID, actual = actual, preds = preds)
dt
}
feval(preds,dtrain)
```